# Force WordPress installation in SSL / HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, https

I have a VPS on which I serve my domain and where I have all the WordPress installation files. The domain is served with SSL over CloudFlare.

Problem is that the markup inside the installation files does not use `https` for stylesheets, JS files, etc. They are always served over `http` and Google or WordPress docs do not help with solving this issue. With this being said, the installation layout looks pretty ugly without any loaded stylesheet whatsoever, or JS functionality.

I certainly doubt that `.htaccess` rewrites would help with this.

How do you enforce WordPress installation over HTTPS?

(This is how the markup actually looks like, and see the URL in the address bar)
[image]

Comment: There is nothing to do with SSL and WordPress installlation. WordPress can be installed in any domain. I think you are facing the issue called mixed content which is quite common with HTTPS domain.

Comment: is your siteurl is set to https version? you can check this by either from database or wp admin->settings->general settings

Comment: @Tristup The issue is with Wordpress-generated URLs.

Comment: @bfontaine, I think that is not like that, actually the omerowitz is mentioning the setup-config.php which called during the WordPress setup. And given screenshot of it. So I mentioned that WordPress installation is not depend on the HTTPs.

Answer (score 0):

if your web server is running Nginx, you can easily redirect all of your HTTP traffic to HTTPS by adding the following code to your Nginx config file. This is the recommended method for redirecting WordPress running on Nginx.

```
server { listen 80;server_name domain.com www.domain.com;xamplereturn 301[https://ez.com$request_uri][1];}
```